# Working with menu

Tags: .net, asp.net

I did a dynamic menu using xmdatasource. It doen't work but I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

```
 <asp:XmlDataSource ID="xmlsource1"
   runat="server" DataFile="~/menu.xml"></asp:XmlDataSource>

<asp:Menu ID="dymenu1"  runat="server" DataSourceID="xmlsource1" Orientation="Horizontal">
  <DynamicMenuStyle BackColor="#228B22" />
  <StaticSelectedStyle BackColor="#FFBB77" />
  <DynamicSelectedStyle BackColor="#FFAA99" />
  <DynamicMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="5px" VerticalPadding="2px" />
  <StaticHoverStyle BackColor="#abcdaa" Font-Bold="False" ForeColor="White" />
  </asp:Menu>
```

This is the xml file

```
 <Menu text="Issue1" url="Issue1.aspx">
<MenuItems>
<MenuItem text="Concept1" url="Concept1.aspx"></MenuItem>
<MenuItem text="Concept2" url="Concept2.aspx">
  </MenuItem>
<MenuItem text="Concept3" url="Concept3.aspx"></MenuItem>
</MenuItems>
</Menu>
 <Menu text="Issue2" url="Issue2.aspx">
<MenuItems>
<MenuItem text="Problem1" url="Problem1.aspx"></MenuItem>
<MenuItem text="Problem2" url="Problem2.aspx"></MenuItem>
</MenuItems>
```

can u please let me know where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Do you get an error? What doesn't work?

Comment: the menu does'nt get displayed..

Answer (score 0):

You must define the [`DataBindings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.menu.databindings.aspx) property so the Menu control knows on which fields to perform binding.